# Word press won't post or update if there is code in the page

Tags: posts

After more than ten years without a problem WordPress will not post or update if there is code in the post.

Any help would be appreciated

Ps I have already tried disabling all plugins

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific? Keep in mind this stack is for developer questions rather than user support. Have you checked the browsers dev console? When you say code do you mean code that's to be viewed by the user or are you literally writing javascript script tags to _execute_ in your post content? Which editor are you using? If it does not save/update what does it do instead?